# Android: Add cells to GridView dynamically?

Tags: android, gridview

I am want to add cells to `GridView` dynamically when the user reach the last row of cells its like the show more?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [CommonsWare EndlessAdapter](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless). Very straight-forward `Adapter` implementation.

You could also manually use an `OnScrollListener` on the `GridView`. Use the `onScrollStateChanged()`  callback to figure out when the grid is `OnScrollListener.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE`, then determine if the last grid item is visible. If so, get more items for your `Adapter`, and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`.